# weird netstat result what does this mean why is my computer connected to itself

Tags: cmd.exe, netstat

`netstat` shows following results:

```
ACTIVE CONNECTNONS
PROTO      LOCAL ADDRES          FOREIGN ADDRESS
TCP        127.0.0.1:54964       MYCOMPUTER:54965
TCP        127.0.0.1:54965       MYCOMPUTER:54964
```

Is this like my computer connected to itself?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you are right.  There are some applications and processes that rely on loopback port for inter-process communications.  To find out which process(es) was involved, use the command `netstat -b`.

Answer (score 3):

What you are observing is a common approach to [Inter-Process Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) used widely in *nix systems.

Processes are are self contained, so in order to share information between them, some kind of intermediary is required. sometimes files, databases ,and shared objects in memory are used, but these are subject to race conditions and locking issues. Using a network stream to communicate is simple and well supported, and opens up possibilities like event-driven logic.